# Not able to properly cold-sign and then send Bitcoin tx using cold/online node separation

Tags: bitcoin

this is one of my first posts on stack, so forgive me if I do something wrong. what I am trying to do is to achieve proper cold-signing of bitcoin transaction via RPC. I got stuck on last step with "64: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)" and cannot proceed further.

The architecture I am working with is:

- One BTC full-node (core v0.16.1) which is accessible in local network only. This node has full wallet-data including private keys, but does not have blockchain and does not perform any P2P activity. This is my offline node.
- One BTC full-node (core v0.16.1) which has publicly available P2P port, is synced to the bitcoin network, and has read-only wallet. This is my online node.

What I want to do is to use online node to create raw transaction, then forward it to offline one for signing and then broadcast to network using online node. Unfortunately I am not able to accomplish it. All interactions with nodes are being done via RPC.

What I do is:

Generate new address in offline node:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getnewaddress",
    "params": []
}
```

Import this newly created address as watch-only to online node:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "importaddress",
    "params": ["address","",false]
}
```

Then I send some BTCs to this address and wait for confirmations. I check UTXOs data on online node using:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "listunspent",
    "params": [3]
}
```

In the result of that call I find output from the transaction I previously sent. I copy txid, vout, scriptPubKey of the corresponding UTXO and proceed to create raw transaction still on online node. Lets assume my UTXO has txid of ABC, vout 0 and amount of 0.002.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "createrawtransaction",
    "params": [
        [
            {"txid":"ABC","vout": 0}    
        ],
        {
            "someChangeAddress": "0.0005",
            "someOtherAddress": "0.001"   
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a tranaction I am creating to send 0.001 BTC to someOtherAdress paying 0.0005 BTC for it and sending remaining 0.0005 BTC to someChangeAddress. This call returns me valid transaction hex. I skip `fundrawtransaction` as I do not need automatic fee estimation and then I try to send this raw transaction to offline node for signing:

```
 {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "signrawtransaction",
    "params": [
        "transHex",
        [
            {"txid":"ABC","vout":0,"scriptPubKey":"utxoPubKey" }    
        ]
    ]
 }
```

This, once again returns me transaction hex, the `complete` field in returned JSON is set to true so it should be ready to broadcast. I take returned hex and try to sendit via online node:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "sendrawtransaction",
    "params": [
        "signedTransHex"
    ]
}
```

I would expect at this point to have txid returned which then I can observe, but what I get is:

```
{
    "result":null,
    "error":{
        "code":-26,
        "message":"64: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)"
    },
    "id":1
}
```

What do I do wrong? Is the problem related to having the address which UTXO I am using as watch-only on oneline node? But this should not matter since I am either way signing it on cold wallet. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem and fix the issue. The answer for my problems is that since v0.16 the amount is required to be passed with corresponding UTXOs to `signrawtransaction` command. This has been submited as bug in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12429 .